# Why does the dropdown displays options one by one on first click when using append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
     $(document).on('focus', '.resource_person', function() {

        var topic_code = $(this).attr('id');
        var rp_reference = $(this).attr('selected-rp');
        var option = '';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: siteUrl + 'course_management/Training_courses/topic_rp',
            data: {topic_code: topic_code},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(source) {
                $('.resource_person[id="'+topic_code+'"]').empty();

                for (var key in source) {
                    if (source[key] != rp_reference) {
                        option += '<option value="'+source[key]+'">'+key+'</option>';
                    } else {
                        option += '<option value="'+source[key]+'" selected="">'+key+'</option>';
                    }
                }

                console.log(option);

                $('.resource_person[id="'+topic_code+'"]').append(option);
            }
        });
    });
```

[This what was happening when I first click the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqh1Q.jpg)

[After clicking it for the second time it goes back to the normal behavior of dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGRya.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first click it makes request causing delay to show items, but it uses cahce on second request.

If you force request not to use cache, same delay will happen every time:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //other options...
});
```

> Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and
>   GET requests.

Comment: "Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests." as said on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: But you gave me an idea thank you. I solved my problem by adding a loading on click so that the dropdown wont show its content before the append.